# ZonedDateTime parses successfully but output string is different

Tags: java, java-8, zoneddatetime

I am using the `ZonedDateTime` to parse and get current time according to the time zone.

When I parse the following `String`, the parse succeeds but the output `String` is different. Why is that?

```
String dateTimeString = "2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00[Europe/Paris]";
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(dateTimeString);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

Output

```
2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00[Europe/Paris]
2016-05-04T12:58:22+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

At what point did it decide to change `+1` to `+2` and why wasn't an exception thrown?

I understand that the parameter in the parenthese `[Europe/Paris]` is optional but here it takes precedence over the offset.

On the other hand the following code

```
String dateTimeString = "2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00";
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(dateTimeString);
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

produces output

```
2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00
2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, that `2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00[Europe/Paris]` is not a correct time, as we have CEST (Central European Summer Time, Daylight Saving Time) in May which starts at the last Sunday in March. It is +2h compared to UTC. So indeed `2016-05-04T12:58:22+02:00[Europe/Paris]` is correct.

As you said, `[Europe/Paris]` seems to take precendence. Not sure if there should be an exception in respect to the spec, but I doubt it.

To put it differently `2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00` can not be in the time zone `Europe/Paris`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that it is a wrong date, why does it parse successfully? That's a design flaw.

Comment: I would guess there is a defined precedence in the spec. But I didn't check that.

Answer (score 1):

### Feature; not a bug.

The `ZonedDateTime#parse` gives higher precedence to `ZoneId` than `ZoneOffset`. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) mentions it clearly:

> In terms of design, this class should be viewed primarily as the
> combination of a `LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId`. The `ZoneOffset` is a
> vital, but secondary, piece of information, used to ensure that the
> class represents an instant, especially during a daylight savings
> overlap.

It can be further understood by looking into the decompiled source code:

**class ZonedDateTime**

```
public static ZonedDateTime parse(CharSequence text) {
    return parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
}

public static ZonedDateTime parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(formatter, "formatter");
    return formatter.parse(text, ZonedDateTime::from);
}

public static ZonedDateTime from(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
    if (temporal instanceof ZonedDateTime) {
        return (ZonedDateTime) temporal;
    }
    try {
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.from(temporal);
        if (temporal.isSupported(INSTANT_SECONDS)) {
            long epochSecond = temporal.getLong(INSTANT_SECONDS);
            int nanoOfSecond = temporal.get(NANO_OF_SECOND);
            return create(epochSecond, nanoOfSecond, zone);
        } else {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(temporal);
            LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(temporal);
            return of(date, time, zone);
        }
    } catch (DateTimeException ex) {
        throw new DateTimeException("Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: " +
                temporal + " of type " + temporal.getClass().getName(), ex);
    }
}
```

**class ZoneId**

```
public static ZoneId from(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
    ZoneId obj = temporal.query(TemporalQueries.zone());
    if (obj == null) {
        throw new DateTimeException("Unable to obtain ZoneId from TemporalAccessor: " +
                temporal + " of type " + temporal.getClass().getName());
    }
    return obj;
}
```

**class TemporalQuery**

```
public static TemporalQuery<ZoneId> zone() {
    return TemporalQueries.ZONE;
}

static final TemporalQuery<ZoneId> ZONE = new TemporalQuery<>() {
    @Override
    public ZoneId queryFrom(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
        ZoneId zone = temporal.query(ZONE_ID);
        return (zone != null ? zone : temporal.query(OFFSET));// <----- Look at this line
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Zone";
    }
};
```

Also, the whole point of `ZonedDateTime` is that you include `ZoneId` in it so that it can automatically give you the correct date-time considering **Summer Time / Daylight Saving Time** e.g. in absence of the `ZoneId` information, the following code will give you the same output for both print statements:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeString = "2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00";
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00
2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00
```

Again, it's a feature; not a bug because you asked the system to parse the date-time string with a **fixed** `ZoneOffset` information. For a simple analogy, you can think of `ZoneOffset` to be evaluated literally while `ZoneId` to be evaluated variably.

**A couple of things which may be useful for you and the future visitors:**

1. The date-time string, `2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00[Europe/Paris]` is already in the default format used by [`ZonedDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and therefore, you do not need to pass a `DateTimeFormatter` to it as an argument.
2. `System.out.println` prints the string returned by `toString` method of the parameter object automatically and therefore you do not need to call `toString` explicitly.

Thus your code,

```
import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeString = "2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00[Europe/Paris]";
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
    }
}
```

can be simply written as

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeString = "2016-05-04T12:58:22+01:00[Europe/Paris]";
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}
```